# Simple pendulum: How to solve the following second order nonlinear ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm trying to find equation of motion the following pendulum.

[image]

To do this, let 
$$\vec r (t) = (l \sin (\theta (t)), -l \cos(\theta(t))).$$

then 
$$m D^2 \vec r(t) = ( -l \sin(\theta(t))\cdot \dot{\theta}(t) + l\cos(\theta(t)) \cdot \ddot{\theta}(t) , -l\cos(\theta(t)) \cdot \dot{\theta}(t) - l \sin(\theta(t)) \ddot{\theta}(t) ) = (mg (-\hat y)) + \vec T.$$

By observing that the bob does not move in the radial direction, we can conclude that the net force on the radial direction has to be zero at any given moment, hence 
$$T = mg\cos(\theta(t)).$$

Therefore, for $\theta = \theta(t)$, we get (x-axis)

$$ -l \sin(\theta)\cdot \dot{\theta} + l\cos(\theta) \cdot \ddot{\theta} = - mg\cos(\theta) \sin(\theta),$$

and (y-axis)
$$-l\cos(\theta) \cdot \dot{\theta} - l \sin(\theta) \ddot{\theta}  = mg - mg\cos^2 (\theta).$$

so, the function $\theta(t)$ must satisfy both of these DEs at the same time.

However, anyone to took freshman year physics courses solves this problem by noting that $r = l \theta$, which is kind of weird considering the fact that what I have to solve in order to get the solution.

---

**Question:**

How to solve these above second order nonlinear ODEs ?

I have tried Laplace transform an got, for $L (\theta (t)) = F(s)$

$$F'(s) = (-1) \frac{(s^2 + 1 + g/l)}{s} F(s) +\frac{ \dot\theta(0)}{s} + \theta(0),$$

however, I do not know how transfer back the solution to the above first order ODE analytically, so leave that there.

Comment: what is the reason for the down vote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **first error** in your first equation
$$
\ddot{\pmb r}(t)=\left(-l\sin\theta\;\dot\theta^2+l\cos\theta\;\ddot\theta,\;l\cos\theta\;\dot\theta^2+l\sin\theta\;\ddot\theta\right)
$$
that is $$
m\ddot{\pmb r}(t)=-mg\hat y+\pmb T
$$
and we have
\begin{align}
ml(\ddot{\theta}\cos\theta-\dot{\theta}^2\sin\theta)&=-T\sin\theta. & \tag {eq. 1} \\
ml(\ddot{\theta}\sin\theta+\dot{\theta}^2\cos\theta )&=T \cos\theta - mg  & \tag {eq. 2}
\end{align}
Observe that $T\neq mg\cos\theta$ (this is your **second error**).

Taking the difference $\sin\theta\times (\text{eq. }1)-\cos\theta \times (\text{eq. }2)$ we find
$$ ml\dot\theta^2=T-mg\cos\theta \tag 3$$
and taking the sum $\cos\theta\times (\text{eq. }1)+\sin\theta \times (\text{eq. }2)$ we find
$$ ml\ddot\theta=-mg\sin\theta \tag 4$$
that is 
\begin{align}
ml\dot\theta^2+mg\cos\theta &=T\tag 5\\
\ddot\theta+\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta &=0 \tag 6
\end{align}

I think you can solve these equations.

Comment: However, by doing that, in order to say that both DEs describe the same motion, we need to show that both have the same solutions. It is clear that the solutions of  those nonlinear equation, satisfies the last equation you gave; however for the other direction, we need to divide those simple equations with $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$, which we cannot that since those functions becomes zero for some values of $t$, so how would you argue that both equations describes the same motion ?

Comment: $\sin\theta=0$ and $\cos\theta=0$ are subcases of eq. 1 and eq. 2

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot both for the answer and the response.

Comment: By the way, I noticed right now, why $T \not = mg \cos\theta$ ? The bob does not move in the radial direction at any given instant, so shouldn't the zero on the radial axis be zero all the time ?

Comment: See eq. 5! you must consider the radial acceleration.

Comment: You're right, I totally forgot that.